# How do I change which AirPod audio input comes from?

Tags: audio, airpods

My AirPods are suddenly not working for audio input and I remember there was a way to force the OS to use the left or right one but I don't remember whether it was iOS or macOS. `Sound Preferences` on the macOS doesn't seem to give me the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - just found it in iOS. You go to Bluetooth, select the (i) info icon to the right of the AirPods and then at the bottom is a `Microphone` options: `Automatically Switch AirPods` or `Always Left/Right AirPod`.